# Custom Segmented Control (UIView) In Front of Pushed View

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, collectionview

Hi I have implemented a custom animated push when my collection View Cell is tapped. The issue I'm having is that when this view controller is pushed forward, my custom segmented controller is on top of it still. Here is my code for my push:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let vc = PopUpCellViewController(nibName: "PopUpCellViewController", bundle: nil)
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    sourceCell = cell
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

}
```

Let me know if you can help me put this Segmented control below my "PopUpCellViewController" when it is called.

[image]

Comment: Are you using a story board? Would you be able to provide screen shots of your story board?

Comment: @DonovanKing i am not using story board. all done programmatically

Comment: Is the  Segmented control in the navigation bar? Would you be willing to post screen shots of what's happening?

Comment: @DonovanKing added picture

Answer (score 1):

You are probably adding your custom segmented controller as a subview to the navigation bar. Never do that: you must not add *any* subviews to a navigation bar. Instead, make the segmented controller your view controller's `navigationItem.titleView`. It will then occupy the center of the navigation bar, but only in that one view controller (not after the push).